# Coldfusion DateFormat() / TimeFormat() functions to Ruby Time/strftime()

Tags: ruby, coldfusion, cfml

I have the following code on my Coldfusion:

```
<CFSET ID="TIM#DateFormat(now(), 'YYYYMMDD')##TimeFormat(Now(),'HHmmssl')#">
<cfoutput>ID=#ID#</cfoutput>
```

That produces (different on time, of course):

```
ID=TIM20150907072315344
```

I try to get the same result with ruby but I'm stuck at:

```
t = Time.new()
ID = t.strftime("%Y%m%d")
puts "ID=TIM#{ID}"
```

output:

```
ID=TIM201509
```

I'm stuck on producing the output of `TimeFormat(Now(),'HHmmssl')`

Any help?

EDIT:
Maybe something like:

```
t.strftime("%H%M%S%L")
```

?

Comment: Did you bother checking: http://apidock.com/ruby/Time/strftime ?

Comment: Yes, I did bother, thanks for the tip ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the format of the datetime output in both languages. Your desired string would be:

```
ID = Time.­new().strf­time("TIM%­Y%m%d%H%M%­S%L")
```

in Ruby and...

```
<cfset ID = ("TIM" & dateTimeFormat(now(), "yyyymmddHHnnssl"))>
```

in Coldfusion.

You can test these simple things online by visiting free services like [trytuby.org](http://tryruby.org/) and [trycf.com](http://trycf.com/)